# 960 grid conflicting with wordpress IE 7 / 8 sidebar on bottom

Tags: html, wordpress, css, sidebar, 960.gs

I just validated my site with w3c, except the & errors link i have to replace with just & for the googlemaps link.

But in IE 7/8 is the site conflicting with the layout

the sidebar is still placed in the bottom of the page. ( should i fix this in the IE.css or is 't another bug?

So has anyone experience with this issue?

http://rikvandoorn.nl/waldorf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed with the validation and solved it with the IE.css